# How to write inverse in CVX (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-algebra, cvx

[image]

My attempt of `cvx` (Matlab) for `n = 2`:

```
A = diag([3 2]);
cvx_begin
variable X(2,2) symmetric
minimize (trace(A*inv(X)*A*X'))
subject to
X>0;
cvx_end
```

I have the following error:

[image]

From my understanding, inverse cannot be used in `cvx`, is there any other way to rewrite the question?

P.S.: How to type latex in stackoverflow? $$ are not working here

Comment: Latex does not work in stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't think `cvx` accepts inverses. Generally this is because you never want to compute numerically the inverse of a matrix, its unstable often. However, in your case, its in the definition of the equation, so you may need to do some shenanigans to that equation to get rid of the inverse, no idea. Given that this looks like  homework, you should have a wider context of what is expected of you.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks for comment. It is not a homework, it can from research analysis.

Comment: Ah fair, apologies, its "homework season" so I tend to think posts are :) . I think this starts to become a maths question, as inverses of matrices are really something to avoid. But in your case is the variable to find, so shoud be good. No idea sorry. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps you might get an answer sooner if you ask on the [CVX Forum](http://ask.cvxr.com/).